# Custom +/- 10% Band from geom_abline?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot that compares measured to predicted values where the line going through the plot is of the form `y = 0 + x`. I would like to then shade the region +/- 10% from the line. Is there a way to do this without adding a column of data to the data.frame?

**Code**

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Fake Data - Not my real data
N <- 1e3
x <- runif(N, 200, 600)
a <- 0
b <- 1
y_true <- a + b * x
sigma <- 50
y <- rnorm(N, y_true, sigma)

d <- tibble(y, x)

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_abline(slope = 1) +
    #geom_ribbion(aes(x = ? * .9, y = ? * 1.1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Is your real example a simple linear model like this?  If so, you may be able to base your ribbon off `stat = "smooth"` using `lm` as the method. That will calculate the line (predicted mean), and you can then build the ribbon off those calculated values via `stat()`.  Something like `geom_ribbon(stat = "smooth", method = "lm", aes(ymin = stat(y*.9), ymax = stat(y*1.1) ), alpha = 0.25)`.

Comment: @aosmith Unfortunately it's not. If I use the `lm` method, it offsets the band a little too much. I had never heard of the `stat()` function before though, so that's cool.

Comment: @aosmith Actually, it seems if I do, `geom_ribbon(stat = "smooth", method = "lm", formula = y ~ 0 + x, aes(ymin = stat(y*.9), ymax = stat(y*1.1) ), alpha = 0.25)` That gives me the shaded region I need.